# How long is it safe to store rice horchata for?

Tags: storage-lifetime, rice, mexican-cuisine, smoothie

I have a recipe for Mexican *horchata*, which is a kind of smoothie made with rice. However, it doesn't specify how long I can store it for, and as rice can be dangerous if stored incorrectly I don't want to risk it. Any ideas how long I can keep it for?

Comment: Maybe worth putting the word "rice" in the title to disambiguate which type of horchata you're asking about.

Comment: I imagine the sugar in horchata will have a faster impact on it going bad than the rice.  Most sweet beverages will begin to turn after only a day or two--depending on temperature, etc.

Comment: I'm also curious about your "smoothie" claim... I've never had horchata that had a consistency any thicker than thin milk.  Is this a different variety of horchata you're making?

Comment: Sugar is a preservative, so if anything it will help the horchata keep longer. As for the smoothie, it was more a reference to the fact that you blitz milk, rice and various ingredients together rather than a claim of consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one recipe specifies “[horchata will keep in the fridge for up to 7 days](http://www.casadelasolas.com/horchata-dairy-free-gluten-free-freshing-a-drink-in-mexico/),” another “[up to four days](http://www.davidlebovitz.com/2011/06/horchata-recipe-mexican-rice-drink/),” others more vaguely “[a few days](http://forbiddenriceblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/homemade-horchata/)” or “[several days](http://www.texascooking.com/recipes/horchata.htm).” Note that it also depends on whether the recipe you're using adds milk or not, if it “[is made without milk it will keep in the frig for various days](http://www.justapinch.com/recipes/drink/non-alcoholic-drink/mexican-rice-milk-horchata-mexicana.html).” Probably the best piece of advice is this one:

> Horchata will keep in the refrigerator for 3 to 5 days; use common sense.
>
> *From: http://www.loveveggiesandyoga.com/2012/03/homemade-horchata.html*